# Spring Mongodata Aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I tried to implement an aggregation with the simple sum operation using **spring-data-mongodb -> 1.10.11.RELEASE** 
I tried the following query

```
db.transaction.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id:"null",
        netBalance: {
            $sum: "$netBalance"
        },
        referalBalance: {
            $sum: "$referalBalance"
        }
    }
}])
```

And the output on my terminal is

```
{ "_id" : "null", "netBalance" : 587432, "referalBalance" : 2940 }
```

When I tried same query, using spring mongodata

```
Aggregation aggregation = 
      Aggregation.newAggregation(
             Aggregation.group("netBalance")
                        .sum("netBalance")
                        .as("netBalance"));
```

The result is not same as the terminal output, also I am not able to add a second field on the query. How can I modify the spring mongodata call to have the same query?

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the output of the second query?

Comment: you can verify in the application logs what is the actual aggregation query generated by spring data mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with spring you're grouping by netBalance instead of null in shell. To reproduce, just leave group param empty (null will throw an error)
Then you can apply sum on second field .

Try this code (not tested, but must work):

```
Aggregation aggregation = 
      Aggregation.newAggregation(
             Aggregation.group()
                        .sum("netBalance").as("netBalance")
                        .sum("referalBalance").as("referalBalance"));
```